# Getting an ambiguous reference when using imagePickerController Delegate function below:

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to have override the imagePickerController function that is in the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. However, i seem to be getting an error :

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
```

I have done multiple google searches and this seems to be working fine for everyone else?

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){


    myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the wrong signature for the delegate method. It should be:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

Comment: You'll need this answer for Swift 3