# SWIFT | photo gallery not opening

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uitapgesturerecognizer, photo-gallery

[image]i have created an app menu where users can click on a photo and the pic is displayed in an alertView and there i have added 2 actions -> One of the action being cancel and other action being edit images which should open gallery to select some other image. however when i click on the edit button(which has code added) It does nothing and work same as to dismiss the alert view.
the code for the ALERTVIEW is

```
@objc func taxImageTApped(_snder:UITapGestureRecognizer)    {
    print("TaxImage")


    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Tax Image", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backimg@3x.png")
    let uiImageAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let scaleSze = CGSize(width: 245, height: 245/image.size.width*image.size.height)
    let reSizedImage = image//.resize(newSize: scaleSze)
    uiImageAlertAction.setValue(reSizedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
    alertView.addAction(uiImageAlertAction)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style:   UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default) {action in

    let newImage = UIImagePickerController()
    newImage.delegate = self
    newImage.sourceType =   UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    newImage.allowsEditing = false
    })
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
    /////////////////////below is details for tap gesture i have        applied on //the label    
    taxImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    taxImageView.textColor = tableTextColor
    taxImageView.text = "View Image"
    taxImageView.textAlignment = .left
    taxImageView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "View Image", attributes:
        [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
    editInfoView.addSubview(taxImageView)
    taxImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoView.leftAnchor, constant: 260).isActive = true
    taxImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoView.topAnchor, constant: 740).isActive = true
    taxImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    taxImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    taxImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let taxImageGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(taxImageTApped))
    taxImageGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    taxImageGesture.isEnabled = true
    taxImageGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    taxImageView.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(taxImageGesture)
    taxImageView.addGestureRecognizer(taxImageGesture)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

**Create variable in controller**

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
```

**Add this is in viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    }
```

**Call this function from where you want or you can add as gesture method also**

```
func addActionSheet() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let galleryOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    let cameraOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    let deleteOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.imageView.image = nil
    })

    let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    alertController.addAction(galleryOption)
    alertController.addAction(cameraOption)
    alertController.addAction(deleteOption)
    alertController.addAction(cancelOption)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Add Delegate method of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` or `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to get image**

```
extension ControllerName: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        self.imageView.image = image
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Call addActionSheet function from taxImagedTappedGesture method and tell me what happens?

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'   -  error in every cameraoption, galleryoption lines , and

Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'    - error in UIIMAGECONTROLLERORIGINALIMAGE   line

also, can not call the function since not declared inside taximagegesture method

Comment: Can you add property list from info.plist Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description and Camera usage Description ?

Comment: Which swift version are you using? Mine answer is for swift 4.2 and Ambiguous references to member 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' can solve this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760031/getting-an-ambiguous-reference-when-using-imagepickercontroller-delegate-functio

Comment: Because same code, I implemented it's working fine with these functionalty camera, gallery, delete photo, and cancel

Comment: let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController() Add this variable in controller and add this code in viewDidLoad ->                                                         
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

Comment: Can you please try this which I mention in the comment? and tell me what happened?

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' this is still left in UIIMAGECONTROLLERORIGINALIMAGE line brother

Comment: Did you try which I mention in a comment? and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method I wrote in answer, you just have to change your controller name, That's it!!

Answer (score 1):

**Create NSObject class for Camera and Gallery.**

```
import UIKit

class CameraHandler: NSObject{

//MARK:- Shared Instance
static let shared = CameraHandler()
private override init() {

}

//MARK:- Variables
var currentVC: UIViewController!

//MARK: Internal Properties
var imagePickedBlock: ((UIImage) -> Void)?

//MARK:- Open Camera
func camera() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
        currentVC.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//MARK:- Open Gallery
func photoLibrary() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        currentVC.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//MARK:- ActionSheet For Options
func showActionSheet(vc: UIViewController) {
    currentVC = vc
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.camera()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.photoLibrary()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    vc.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

 //MARK:- UIImagePickerController Delegate Methods
extension CameraHandler: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    currentVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imagePickedBlock?(image)
    }else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
    currentVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Use Below code in your view controller:

**For showing alert in current view controller:**

```
CameraHandler.shared.showActionSheet(vc: self)
```

**To get the selected image:**

```
CameraHandler.shared.currentVC = self      
CameraHandler.shared.imagePickedBlock = {(image) in
      print(image)
    }
```

Comment: declaration for camerahandler?

Comment: CameraHandler is a singleton class. I have already declared with static keyword. so, no need to declared again.  You can call any function by just typing: 
CameraHandler. shared.FunctionName

Comment: but it is giving  errors for this code, one is expected declaration for camerahandler and currentVC

Comment: can you provide me the screenshot. So that i can check.

Comment: i dont think we can add image in comments, i will do some more research on it and get back it to you tomorrow, hoping it works

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K-7XgIa9f0HWciNUga6WZpGoXPvrW_uB

still no luck

Comment: You are going wrong. You are using Extension of CameraHandler class but there is no CameraHandler class in your project. Thats why, there are errors of undeclared type.
         **Follow these steps and then try**
         1.  Create a new swift file. Copy and paste the above "CameraHandler" class code in it.
         2.  Add the below code in your class where you want to access the gallery.